# Можно ли сказать что литерал 1 является экземпляром типа int?

Tags: c++

Можно ли сказать что литерал `1` является экземпляром типа int? Я знаю, что число `1` в коде является литералом, но можно ли сказать что это - экземпляр типа `int`, например когда у нас есть функция `foo()` и она возвращает `1`.

Comment: Мне кажется, что нет - в том плане, что адрес этого объекта не существует.  Но это явное *значение* типа `int`, но не экземпляр, под которым обычно понимается lvalue. Не более чем imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ваш код похож на этот, то литерал исчезает как только попадает в оператор `return` функции возвращающей `int`:

```
int foo() {
    // здесь '1' - это литерал
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    // функция foo имеет тип int
    // в этом коде литералов нет, а есть значение типа int
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не могли бы вы уточнить: можно ли сказать, что значение типа int, это - экземпляр типа int?

Comment: Слова "значение" и "экзепляр" взаимозаменяемы в этом контексте. Вообще значение всегда одно, а экземпляров с одним и тем же значением может быть много. C++ копирует значения при возврате из функции. Скорее всего у нас тут будет одно значение и два экземпляра: один экземпляр внутри функции и один в коде который её вызвал. На практике их смешивают без всякого вреда.